# Comma after em-dash

Tags: commas, em-dashes, exclamations

I have seen many questions on this, but all the answers seem to address the example—how the use of em-dash may be avoided using some other forms of punctuation in that particular example—and not the concept in general. And it feels like I have a *very* particular example at hand that seems like it would really be better with a pair of em-dash, and the latter seemingly *must* be followed by a comma.

> If *P*₃ has to lie—and it has to lie to improve its chances beyond ₁—, using one of its given superpowers will be its best strategy, given that they are ultimately potent and incur the lowest risk possible of getting caught.

Options considered:

1. Dropping the comma after the em-dash: This is no good. The sentence without the em-dashes and the supplementary expression within must make sense, and it doesn't without that comma.
2. Replacing em-dashes with parentheses: Works, but given how exclamatory the supplementary expression is, parentheses around it doesn't suit as well.
3. Replacing the first em-dash with comma and leaving out the second: Makes it hard to connect the if-clause to its then-clause.

Comment: #1 is the classic use of paired em-dashes. You may have misunderstood, but this is good to use.

Comment: @YosefBaskin How so? "If P₃ has to lie using one of its given superpowers will be its best strategy, [...]" sounds totally off to me, which is what you get when you take out the em-dashed expression.

Comment: No, native speakers don't see it that way. The feeling of a big break remains: "If P₃ has to lie [MAJOR PAUSE BIGGER THAN A COMMA] using one of its given superpowers will be..." If you don't buy that, don't use the pair, and don't use the dash & comma together.

Comment: #2 is equally good, with a comma: "If P₃ has to lie (and it must, to improve its chances beyond ₁), using one of its given superpowers will be..."

Comment: No, there should not be a comma after the em dash. You can use a pair of commas instead, or the pair of em dashes alone.

Comment: As a matter of emphasis, from less to more, it usually goes (1) parenthesis, (2) commas, (3) em  dashes. People don't like a lot of willy-nilly em dashes, in general, unless it's Emily Dickinson or something like that.

Comment: Will you please step back and explain how you see an em-dash as different from any other dash?